# Hide/un-hide directory and open directory based on argument

Tags: file-system, bash

This code checks to make sure a directory is hidden and if not hides it.  Then if hidden it will prompt for password and if password matches it will un-hide it.  There is also an argument to open un-hidden directory too.

```
#! /bin/bash

DIR="path/untitled"
DIR2="path/.untitled"
password="Z2FsdGVkX18vy4f4QRB3qnb5vIWR0x+tlZmdAmPxX8Y="
input=""
result=""

basic()
{
    if [ -d "$DIR" ]
    then
        clear
        mv $DIR $DIR2
    elif [ -d "$DIR2" ]
    then
        echo -n ": "
        read -s input
        result=$(echo "$password"| openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -a -d -salt -pass pass:wtf)

        if [ "$result" = "$input" ]
        then
            clear
            mv $DIR2 $DIR
        else
            clear
        fi
    else
        :
    fi
exit
}

opendir()
{
    if [ -d "$DIR" ]
    then
        clear
        mv $DIR $DIR2
    elif [ -d "$DIR2" ]
    then
        echo -n ": "
        read -s input
        result=$(echo "$password"| openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -a -d -salt -pass pass:wtf)

        if [ "$result" = "$input" ]
        then
            clear
            mv $DIR2 $DIR
            open $DIR
        else
            clear
        fi
    else
        :
    fi
exit
}

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Main ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
    basic
elif [ $# -eq 1 ]
then
    if [ "$1" = "-o" ]
    then
       opendir
    else
        :
    fi  
fi
clear
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ End of File ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Avoid `echo -n`

Avoid using any flags of `echo`, like this, as it's not portable:

> ```
>     echo -n ": "
> ```

This is more portable, and produces the same output:

```
    printf ": "
```

#### Get rid of empty statements

These empty `else` statements are pointless,
I suggest to remove them:

> ```
> else
>     :
> ```

#### Simplify

This can be simplified:

> ```
>     if [ "$result" = "$input" ]
>     then
>         clear
>         mv $DIR2 $DIR
>     else
>         clear
>     fi
> ```

Since in both branches of the if-else you `clear`, this is the same:

```
    clear
    if [ "$result" = "$input" ]
    then
        mv $DIR2 $DIR
    fi
```

#### Quote variables in paths

Typically you should double-quote variables,
especially when used as paths. So instead of this:

> ```
>         mv $DIR2 $DIR
> ```

This is recommended and safer:

```
        mv "$DIR2" "$DIR"
```

#### Avoid duplicated code

The code in `opendir` and `basic` is almost the same.
The only difference I see is the content of the `"$result" = "$input"` conditions.
Consider using a single function with a flag to determine the behavior inside the main conditional.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I updated my code to reflect them.  When you get time please take a look at the new code.